# ggplot facet_grid label superscript

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with putting subscript in `facet_grid` label. Here is 
an example of the work I have been trying to do.

```
df <- data.frame(species=gl(2,10,labels=c('sp1','sp2')),
                 age=sample(3:12,40,replace=T),
                 variable=gl(2,20,labels=c('N1P1 var','N2P1 var')),
                 value=rnorm(40))

test.plot <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=age,y=value)) +
             geom_point() +
             facet_grid(variable~species)
```

Now I want to make by vertical facet label as 'N[1]P[1] var' and so on, 
where the numbers in the squared bracket means subscript.

I have consulted some helps in this platform regarding this, but none helped me. I have used `expression`, `bquote` as suggested, but nothing worked!

Comment: Subscript or superscript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do 2 things: 
first, make your labels as plotmath expressions

```
variable_labels <- 
  c(expression(paste(N[1],P[1]~var)), expression(paste(N[2],P[1]~var)))

df <- data.frame(species=gl(2,10,labels=c('sp1','sp2')),
                 age=sample(3:12,40,replace=T),
                 variable=gl(2,20,labels=variable_labels),
                 value=rnorm(40))
```

And then change the default labeller function in `facet_grid` to `"label_parsed"`

```
test.plot <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=age,y=value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(variable~species, labeller = "label_parsed")
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: @inscaven, Thank you - defining the labels as expressions and setting 'facet_grid' to '"label_parsed"' did work so far. But the 'aes()' for a subsequent geom is not capable of using those as labels, too. Do you have an idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to add that, Interestingly, `expression` is not needed in some cases. For example, setting the labels to be the result of `paste0("10^", e)` where `e` is a numerical value (the exponent), works just the same.