# how can I use math expressions in ggplot2 facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, symbols, superscript

In the following plot, I would like to replace "d" by delta, include a per mil symbol at the end, and use superscripts in: d13C, d15N and d34S.I got it when I use a biplot (e.g. `plot + ylab(expression(paste(delta^{15}, "N (\u2030)")))`). However, in the attached plot, I'm using facet_grid, which may change the way to get it. Here is the script used:

```
group.violin<-ggplot(group.data, aes(x=Culture2, group = Culture2, y=value)) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, color= Species, group = Species), fun = "mean", 
               geom = "line", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5)+
  stat_summary(geom="point")+
  geom_violin(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), alpha = 0.4, color = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), size = 3, color = "black", pch = 21,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, seed = 12))+
  facet_grid(variable ~ Species, scales = "free_y") +
  xlab("")+ 
  ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "grey85", size = 0.1),
        panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",size = 0.1, fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=12, face="italic"),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        strip.text.x=element_text(size=12,face="bold.italic"),
        strip.text.y=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))
```

Thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [ggplot facet_grid label superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355367/ggplot-facet-grid-label-superscript) helps to answer your question. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677633/how-to-add-superscripts-to-facet-labels or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316214/how-to-apply-subscript-in-the-facet-grid-function-of-ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to change your `variable` to be the labels you expect, then add `labeller=label_parsed` to the call to `facet_grid`.

Using my sample data (below), original plotting code:

[image: original plot with no plotmath facet labels]

```r
group.data |>
  transform(
    variable2 = sub("d([0-9]+)(.*)", "delta^{\\1}*'\\2 (\u2030)'", variable)
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=Culture2, group = Culture2, y=value)) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, color= Species, group = Species), fun = "mean", 
               geom = "line", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5)+
  stat_summary(geom="point")+
  geom_violin(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), alpha = 0.4, color = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), size = 3, color = "black", pch = 21,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, seed = 12))+
  facet_grid(variable2 ~ Species, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_parsed) +
  xlab("")+ 
  ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "grey85", size = 0.1),
        panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",size = 0.1, fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=12, face="italic"),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        strip.text.x=element_text(size=12,face="bold.italic"),
        strip.text.y=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image: same plot with plotmath facet labels]

Unfortunately, this drops the bold/italic formatting you `theme`d into the facet labels, so we need to be clearer on those. Further, having bold-italic in the facet strips and just italic in the other poses a small problem ... but I'll hack it into place by using `plotmath`-like `"bolditalic(..)"` expressions (strings) for everything, and then remove the `bold` portion of that string for just the legends.

For this step, we'll transform `Species` as well, then add `scale_colour_discrete` and `_fill_` hacks using `scales::label_parse` for the `labels=` argument.

```r
group.data |>
  transform(
    variable2 = sub("d([0-9]+)(.*)", "bold(delta^{\\1}*'\\2 (\u2030)')", variable),
    Species = sprintf("bolditalic(%s)", Species)
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=Culture2, group = Culture2, y=value)) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, color= Species, group = Species), fun = "mean", 
               geom = "line", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5)+
  stat_summary(geom="point")+
  geom_violin(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), alpha = 0.4, color = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Culture2, y = value, fill = Species), size = 3, color = "black", pch = 21,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, seed = 12))+
  facet_grid(variable2 ~ Species, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_parsed) +
  xlab("")+ 
  ylab("")+
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = function(z) scales::label_parse()(sub("bold","",z)))+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = function(z) scales::label_parse()(sub("bold","",z)))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "grey85", size = 0.1),
        panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",size = 0.1, fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        strip.text.x=element_text(size=12),
        strip.text.y=element_text(size=12))
```

[image: sample plot with strip labels and facet text fixed]

---

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
n <- 420
group.data <- data.frame(Culture2 = sample(c("Auri", "Grav"), size=n, replace=TRUE), value=runif(n), Species=sample(c("Bos", "Cerv", "Equus"), size=n, replace=TRUE), variable=sample(c("d13C", "d15N", "d34S"), size=n, replace=TRUE))
head(group.data)
#   Culture2      value Species variable
# 1     Auri 0.11483254   Equus     d15N
# 2     Auri 0.48275690   Equus     d13C
# 3     Auri 0.97917358   Equus     d34S
# 4     Auri 0.81151679     Bos     d13C
# 5     Grav 0.54291282   Equus     d34S
# 6     Grav 0.07236709    Cerv     d34S
```

Comment: Now I get this error: 
Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:1:22: unexpected symbol
1: bolditalic(Bos/bison sp
                         ^

Comment: Yeah, that's a factor of no sample data in the question and the sample data I made up was imperfect (in the future, it's always better to provide sample/representative data yourself instead of relying on us to make/find something relevant). This error can be fixed by adding single quotes around the `%s`, as in `sprintf("bolditalic('%s')", Species)` in the first `transform`ation. (I'm assuming none of your `Species` values have embedded quotes in them.)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!